# Optional structural typing possibility in C++ or any other language?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, duck-typing, structural-typing

In C++ how to tell compiler that Ogre::Vector3 IS_SAME_AS SomeOtherLIB::Vector3 ?
I feel that.. in languages like c++ which are not structural typed but there are cases when it makes sense.

Normally as game developer when working with 4+ libraries that provide sort or their own Vector3 implementation. The code is littered with ToOgre, ToThis, ToThat conversion function. Thats a lot of Float3 copying around which should not happen on first place.

Is in C++ or any other languages where we dont have to convert (copying) from one type to another which is essentially the samething. But any solution in C++ as most of the good gamedevs libs are for c/c++.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Why is this tagged with OCaml?

Answer (score 19):

If you use templates you can define functions that take any type of argument as long as the necessary operations are defined on that type. Example:

```
class Foo { void quack() {} };
class Bar { void quack() {} };
class Baz {};

template<typename Duck>
void f(Duck d) {
    d.quack();
}
int main() {
    f(Foo()); // works
    f(Bar()); // works
    f(Baz()); // compile error because Baz does not have a quack method
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

While it doesn't suit any situation, templates can give you *"compile-time duck typing"*.

Lets say you have two vector types:

```
struct Vec3A {
    float x, y, z;
};

struct Vec3B {
    float p[3];
};
```

You can define function templates that hide the implementation how of to get the components:

```
template<class T> float get_x(const T&);
template<class T> float get_y(const T&);
template<class T> float get_z(const T&);

template<> float get_x<Vec3A>(const Vec3A& v) { return v.x; }
// ...
template<> float get_x<Vec3B>(const Vec3B& v) { return v.p[0]; }
// ...
```

With such helpers you can now write generic functions that work on both:

```
template<class T> float length(const T& t) {
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(get_x(t), 2), 
                     std::pow(get_y(t), 2),
                     std::pow(get_z(t), 2));
}
```

You can also continue by specializing utilities like `length()` for performance or other reasons, e.g. if a certain vector already has a member function providing you with the length:

```
template<> float length<Vec3C>(const Vec3C& v) {
    return v.length();
}
```

Comment: "compile-time duck typing" is called "structural typing", if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Anybody know if something like this is possible in Java?

Answer (score 2):

If you are really sure in case of non-virtual structures, you can do a reinterpret_cast. However, it's better to:

1. do templated wrapper functions as shown by sepp2k
2. inherit from one of the vectors and add a conversion operator to the other vector
3. add a separate _cast function that does the conversion

Answer (score 1):

[Haxe](http://haxe.org) is a highly portable language with completely optional structural subtyping:

```
typedef Vector3 = { x : double, y : double, z : double };

class FancyVector3 {
    public var x : double, y : double, z : double;

    function dot(Vector3 v) {
        return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
    }

    function length() {
        return Math.sqrt(dot(this));
    }
}
```

Not only is Vector3 an already usable structure, it also acts as a structural interface for other classes.  Such `typedef`'d structs can specify function signatures as well as fields.

Haxe also has a CFFI for talking to C++ (although it still requires conversion methods), and bindings already exist for a few C++ game engines, as well as a variety of lower-level frameworks.  Cross-platform engines written in pure Haxe are also being developed, targeting variously C++, Flash, and JS (both Canvas and WebGL).

This is probably not the solution you are looking for right now, but may become more interesting within a few years.